# Laravel javascript location should be in view or public

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, document-root

I have a javascript that requires a root directory path provided by PHP to call the JSON file.

I'm not sure if this code should be in **public/js** or within my **template.blade.php**?

If it's in **public/js**, then I have to specify a absolute path like below, so everytime I want to change my directory name or domain I have to change the path as well.

> url: "/myBookStore/public/api/book-type/"

```
    <script>
    $().ready(function(){
    $("#book_type").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "/myBookStore/public/api/book-types/" + $("input[name=book_type]").val(),
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(json){
                //do stuff
             }
        });
    });
});
    </script>
```

If I put it in **template.blade.php**, I could use `URL::to('/')` to specify the base url. However It would have to be ***OUTSIDE*** of public folder, I'm not sure if it's good practice?

template.blade.php

```
    <script>
    $().ready(function(){
    $("#book_type").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: {{ URL::to('/') }} + "/api/book-types/" + $("input[name=book_type]").val(),
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(json){
               //do stuff
             }
        });
    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: To comment on part of your question, my Javascript files are usually in the `public/assets` folder, so you can call them via `URL::asset('assets/file.js')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply create a

```
<meta name="base_url" content="{{ URL::to('/') }}">
```

and read the contents of this meta tag with javascript.

jQuery:

```
var url = $('meta[name="base_url"]').attr('content');
```

javascript:

```
var url = document.getElementsByName('base_url')[0].getAttribute('content')
```

This way you can have your javascript in your public js folder and still get the correct url all the time.

Comment: It seems like a good idea! Are you suggesting js files should always be in public folder? Which method do you think is the best?

Comment: I have them minified in public/js and it is working good for me, I try to avoid mixing php in my js

Comment: Thank you very much, This saved my life. It is so simple, but very useful !!